# print Alphabets Aa Bb Cc Dd

Tags: java

I'm trying to print Aa Bb Cc but it always repeat A to z then B to z.

```
char ch, ch2;
    for(ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++){
    for(ch2 = 'a'; ch2 <= 'z'; ch2++)
       System.out.println(ch + "" + ch2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want *nested* loops:

```
for(ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++)
  for(ch2 = 'a'; ch2 <= 'z'; ch2++) {
     /* All combinations of ch and ch2: Aa..AzBa..Bz..Za..Zz */
  }
```

But a *single* one:

```
for(char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++){
   System.out.println(ch + "" + (char)(ch - 'A' + 'a'));
```

**Edit:** what does `(char)(ch - 'A' + 'a')` stand for?

```
 ch             in 'A'..'Z' range (from for loop)
 ch - 'A'       in   0..26  range
 ch - 'A' + 'a' in 'a'..'z' range
```

Finally, since `ch - 'A' + 'a` is of type `int` and want it be `'a'`, not `96` we cast int bak to `(char)` or you can use `Character.toLowerCase(ch)` as M. Prokhorov suggested in comments below:

```
 for(char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++){
   System.out.println(ch + "" + Character.toLowerCase(ch));
```

Comment: can you explain what this means? (char)(ch - 'A' + 'a') thanks :D

Comment: @iDevdevdev, that's how you can get lowercase `char` from uppercase (since `char` is a kind of numeric datatype in Java, and they follow an order). It'll only work like that for latin character chars though, other alphabets might follow different rules.

Comment: I suggest using `Character.toLowerCase(char)` and/or `Character.toUpperCase(char)` instead of adding and subtracting `char`s together.

Comment: @M. Prokhorov: Thank you! `Character.toLowerCase(ch)` is indeed more readable then arithmetics (`C` habit)

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Thanks Character.toLowerCase is more understandable

Answer (score 0):

As @Dmitry indicated, you don't want nested loops.

You can take advantage of the fact that Java `char`s can be converted to and from `int`s due to how characters are represented. See the [Wikipedia article on ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) for more details on that. It also has a handy chart of the ASCII values for each character. For example, `A` is ASCII 65, and `a` is ASCII 97. That being said, you can do arithmetic in order to "convert" between uppercase and lowercase letters. Uppercase and lowercase letters differ by 32.

That being said, you can do this with two lines of code:

```
for(char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++){
   System.out.println(ch + "" + (char)(ch + 32));
```

Or you could also use one of the excellent solutions that @Dmitry suggested.

Comment: Thanks! I'll remember this

Answer (score 0):

How a nested loop works:

Step 1: First, Compiler will check for the condition inside the first for loop.

- If the condition is True then statements inside the For loop will be
  executed. It means, compiler will enter into second For loop (In your case ch has the value 'A'). **Goto
  Step 2**
- If the condition is False then, compiler will exit from For Loop

Step 2: Compiler will check for the condition inside the second for loop.

- If the condition is True, statements inside the second For loop will
  be executed. It means, it will execute from Statement 1 to N.(In your case from 'a' to 'Z')
- If the condition is False, compiler will exit from second For Loop

Step 3: Once it exit from second for loop, compiler will check for the condition inside the for loop (**repeating Step 1** ) (Here your outer loop variable ch will have the value 'B' and so on)

A simple trick could be to intialize your ch2 variable outside the loop and work with a simple loop:

```
char ch, ch2 = 'a';
for(ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++){
   System.out.println(ch + "" + ch2++);}
}
```